# Ubuntu Mate Raspberry PI 4.0 will not boot after 23.10 update

Tags: boot, mate, 23.10

I just completed updating my Raspberry PI 4.0 8G Ubuntu Mate to 23.10. After the reboot, a splash screen stops and the screen goes black. No recovery is possible. I have SD plugged into my other Ubuntu Mate. I am open to suggestions.

After digging, it seems that my replacement USB NIC is not liked by 23.10. BOOT.LOG shows Failed to start networking.service - Raise network interfaces. I have looked at Interfaces and removed the errant code for the USB NIC. This will not boot clean. BOOT.LOG shows the same error.

Update: USBCORE registers the MAC for this TP ether port as CDC_ETHER. The Driver ax88179_178a gets deregistered by CDC_ETHER. The OS thinks this TP is a HUEWI device and not TP. This suggest that this AX88179_178a has be mothballed.

All of the messages for AX88179_178a are for very old builds. There isn't any linux-image-extra-6.5.0-1012-raspi package. So, a whole class of USB dongles based on the AX88179_178a have been discarded on the Raspberry PI 4.0 8G system.

Comment: Update 2: ok. After messing with netplan, I attempted to disable the HUAWEI driver and use the AX88179_178a driver.  Netplan says it was cool. Then the reboot. Black screen of death says that this TP is not liked by Ubuntu. Ubuntu thinks this is HUAWEI driver. It is not.